# How to check if multi_curl is supported on PHP?

Tags: php, windows, curl, wampserver, curl-multi

I have a piece of PHP code that uses cURL to do post requests, it uses the curl_multi_* functions for performance.

It all works fine on my hosted PHP server.

But it fails on my WAMPServer at 127.0.0.1. Single cURL requests work just fine on the WAMPServer, but `curl_multi_select()` only ever returns -1 until the script finally times out.

The code... is Example #1 on PHP.net's manual page on curl_multi_exec: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php
Here's the snippet causing the infinite loop:

```
$active = null;

do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
}
```

Tested with Vista's firewall disabled.

Does anybody know how to get curl_multi_* working on WAMPServer or is there any way to detect support for curl_multi_* from within the PHP script so I could make a fallback?

Comment: if you have enabled curl in your php.ini, you should be good to use multi_curl

Comment: What does `curl_error()` have to say?

Comment: This answer should be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840688/php-single-curl-works-but-multi-curl-doesnt-work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `function_exists('curl_multi_select')` to detect support.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php