# How to run CURL POST commands setting parameters dynamically from file in parallel OS independent?

Tags: file, http, curl

I want to submit some hundred HTTP requests using CURL, preferrably in parallel. 
This request simply shall submit a value to a server.
How can I do this OS independent? 
I started writing a *.txt* file with a lot of lines looking like:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" url = http://localhost:8080/sales?salesAmount=111.91
```

Only the amount will vary.

Maybe better: The file contains only the amounts one in a line and the CURL command just reads each line as a parameter to be inserted into the CURL command!?

Moved to [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/1479193/how-to-run-curl-post-commands-setting-parameters-dynamically-from-file-in-parall)

Comment: sounds like a question for superuser.com , not stackoverflow.com - btw, a slight modification of [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54353191/1067003) should be able to run hundreds, or even thousands of parallel requests very fast (thanks to the power of libcurl's curl_multi api)

Comment: Hmmm,,,I don't know superuser.com. However, I don't want to code such complicated script. I am looking for a simple cURL command option to read a value from a file and put it into a placeholder in that command. (If cURL does provide something like that).

Comment: if you were asking on superuser.com rather than stackoverflow.com , i would point you towards curl's new (available since curl version 7.66)'s `--parallel` argument, but since you're asking on stackoverflow, i'm just voting to close this question as "belongs on superuser.com" instead.

Comment: I posted this question now on superuser.com

Comment: link?   &nbsp;&nbsp;